# Using module method inside class

Tags: ruby

I have

```
/a.rb

require_relative ‘a/b’
module A
  def self.foo
    "HA"
  end
end

/a/b.rb
module A
  class B
    VAR = A.foo * 3
  end
end
```

Unfortunately it errors out as Undefined foo method inside A module and I don't know why.
`A` is used mostly as a namespace, and I've decided to put some methods in there as configuration - they actually set the root of the project and the root + /config directory for configuration purposes.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with the code given. Are you sure you're declaring them in this order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was requiring the file before defining the methods I was using in it.
I was requiring `b.rb` before defining `A::foo`.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like there's more to this story. The code you've given as an example works as-is, without errors:

```
$ irb
2.5.1 :001 > module A
2.5.1 :002?>     def self.foo
2.5.1 :003?>         "HA"
2.5.1 :004?>       end
2.5.1 :005?>   end
 => :foo 
2.5.1 :006 > 
2.5.1 :007 > module A
2.5.1 :008?>     class B
2.5.1 :009?>         VAR = A.foo * 3
2.5.1 :010?>       end
2.5.1 :011?>   end
 => "HAHAHA" 
2.5.1 :012 > A.foo
 => "HA"
```

If your code is arranged across multiple files as you've alluded to, the cause of the problem is most likely to be how those files interact with each other. However, without more information, I can't debug that.

---

You've since edited the file structure in, so the problem has become clear. Your `require_relative` call in `a.rb` comes *before* you define `module A` and `A.foo` - that means the code in `a/b.rb` runs before the code in `a.rb`, so `A.foo` really isn't defined at the point you're trying to call it.

Comment: Updated the snippet with the file structure

Comment: Oh and I have a test on A.foo that works as expected, problem is when I then use it in the separate class